# Time to make n pancakes on a pan that takes k.

Tags: combinatorics

To make a pancake one needs to fry it for one minute on each side. Given $n$ pancakes and a pan that allows to fry $k$ pancakes at the same time, what is the shortest amount of time required?
Example: $n=4$ pancakes and $k=3$ can be fried simultaneously. First fry three on one side, then fry two of them and the remaining one. After that two pancakes will remain that need to be fried on one side, so the answer is three minutes.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Can you find a lower bound based on how many sides of pancakes need to be fried?  Now can you justify that the lower bound can be attained as long as it is at least $2$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For n = 4 and k = 3, Call the pancakes 1,2,3,4, each needing frying on both sides a and b.

For 20 seconds each, do the following batches of 3 :

(1a 2a 3a)

(4a 1b 2b)

(3b 4b 1a)

(2a 3a 4a)

(1b 2b 3b)

(4b 1a 2a)

(3a 4a 1b)

(2b 3b 4b)

So in your example with n=4 and k = 3, the answer is 8 x 20 seconds = 2 minutes 40 seconds.

If n > k or n = k, you can always use a similar pattern of listing 2kn 'frys', each of time 1/k minutes in a 2n x k rectangular array, and so a minimum time of 2n x 1/k = 2n/k minutes.

If n < k just put all the pancakes in at once and cook for 2 minutes.

If you add the restriction of needing each side to Be cooked continuously for a minute, the results are similar. With n > k, the number of minutes needed is the smallest integer not less than 2n/k. Rounding up required if the last batch isn't full.

For n = 4 and k = 3 cook each of these batches for 1 minute :

(1a 2a 3a)
(4a 1b 2b)
(3b 4b   )